# JQuery Paginated Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

I am able to create a paginated table. But what i want to do is be able to set what page it loads on.
For example there are 3 pages and want to be able to make it load on the 2 page and not the first.

Reason is I want to be able to save the page a user is on if the page is refreshed.
But if I can just figure out how to manually load a certain page.
Here is the jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/29W9Q/1088/

I tried adjusting

```
    var cFirstVisible = pageNo
```

But to no avail. I just cant see how to set it

Comment: try saving it in cookies and getting it back

Comment: that can be done with local storage. All modern browsers support it. Example : http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 0):

Using cookies or local storage would indeed suit your needs, but there's something that would exceed your needs too.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers.onhashchange

You can store the current page in the window's location hash, which would look something like `your.domain.com/#page=2` and parse the hash on load. Advantage here is that you've also created a link that can be shared, which could be REALLY useful if the table contains 50 pages.

If you need some more help implementing this feel free to leave a comment, but if you're able to use jquery you should be able to use the location hash too :)

Changing the hash does not reload the page, but does create a hash change event.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I can do this yes, but I dont know how to make the change in the paginated table. like I can get the page number but I cant make the change in the javascript for the table